# Is there a "Railsy" way to query for a union of two separate tables and sort on differently-named columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to query two different tables `books` and `spree_payments`, and sort by comparing a date that is saved on one under the `transaction_date` column of the `Books` table and the `created_at` column of the `Spree::Payments` table. I've used the following SQL query to get partial information about the records from PostGres and sort by an arbitrary index of the resulting tuples, but I'd really like to do this in a more Rails-native way if possible.

```
SELECT 'books', books.id, books.transaction_date FROM books WHERE account_id = user.account.id
UNION
SELECT 'spree_payments', spree_payments.id, spree_payments.created_at FROM spree_payments
                                                                      JOIN spree_orders ON spree_orders.id = spree_payments.order_id
                                                                      JOIN spree_stores ON spree_stores.id = spree_orders.store_id
                                                                      WHERE spree_stores.account_id = user.account.id
ORDER BY 3 desc
limit 25 offset 26
```

Anyone have a suggestion for a better way to query this?

Comment: The query doesn't even make sense at all. When you're using a union you typically want to merge two different result sets that have the same columns together. These have no columns in common. I think what you actually want here is a lateral join.

Comment: @max - apologies, I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting with the lateral join. Conceptually, the `transaction_date` on `books` and `created_at` date on `spree_payments` are meant to represent the same thing: "when did this payment occur". I'd like to be able to pull all of the payments a given account has received and sort based on those dates. A lateral join seems like its meant for propagating data upwards from the `FROM` subqueries, I don't think that's really what I'm doing here. The FROM/JOIN/JOIN that follows the SELECtT on spree_payments is for limiting scope to an account.